# In XPATH, use data from the current context to filter other data

Tags: xpath

Is there a way to use data from the current context to filter nodes somewhere else in the statsource.

For instance, if I have this XML:

```
<root>
    <group1>
        <inst>
            <type>Foo</type>
            <value>First Foo</value>
        </inst>
        <inst>
            <type>Bar</type>
            <value>The Bar</value>
        </inst>
        <inst>
            <type>Foo</type>
            <value>Second Foo</value>
        </inst>
    </group1>
    <group2>
        <Filter>
            <FilterType>Foo</FilterType>
        </Filter>
        <Filter>
            <FilterType>Bar</FilterType>
        </Filter>
    </group2>
</root>
```

Assuming my context is one of the Filter tags, I want to return get the number of instances of the specified type in group1.  I would like to write XPATH that looks something like this:

```
count(/root/group1/inst[type = **FilterType**])
```

Is there anything I can use to get the FilterType in the original context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be done easily in XPath 2.0**:

```
for $type in /*/*/Filter[1]/FilterType
  return 
     count(/*/group1/*[type eq $type])
```

When this Xpath expression is evaluated against the provided XML document, the correct result is returned:

**2**

In XPath 1.0, if the number of `group1/inst` elements is known in advance, and $vType stands for the FilterType in question, then one could construct the following XPath 1.0 expression:

```
  ($vType = /*/group1/inst[1]/type)
 +
  ($vType = /*/group1/inst[2]/type)
 +
  ($vType = /*/group1/inst[3]/type)
```

which again produces:

2.

Finally, if the XPath 1.0 expression is needed in XSLT and the "Filter" is the current node,

then the following XPath expression calculates the exact number of matches:

```
  count(/*/group1/inst[type = curent()/FilterType])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution to the same problem. Currently, I'm using a variable to route around this... it'd look something like the following

```
<xsl:variable name='FilterType'><xsl:value-of select='FilterType'/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select='count(/root/group1/inst[type = $FilterType])'/>
```

But there has to be a better way.